# Is this a hidden scene in Minecraft Story Mode? If so, how do I access it?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

I've played Minecraft Story Mode a lot and finally completed Episode 4. I'm sure I didn't miss anything else. One day I was watching a Google Play commercial when I saw a scene when Jesse, Axel, and Rueben are having a snowball fight. I've never seen this before, and I know it's not going to be in Episode 5 since

> Reuben dies.

I think this video explains it right in 0:07 of this video:

Has this scene been in one of the earlier episodes? Does anyone know about this scene?
I played the game all over again and there was still no scene of this snowball fight.

**Update**: Found some images from [here](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/103477/scene-that-wasn-t-in-the-game-google-play-advert):

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update 2:** I thought at first they were playing in a taiga biome or a snowy biome. But then I noticed there was ice on the left. I think it was an ice spike biome.

**Update 3:** I noticed that the corners were dark. This may be evidence that this is a flashback that's going to be in Episode 5. I'm not sure, but Google Play did spoil us. Image taken [here](http://lunasdestiny.tumblr.com/post/136092399962/this-happens-in-a-google-play-advert-look-at-my):

[image]

Comment: The video was taken down by Google. Maybe it was intended to be added to the game, but they changed their mind?

Comment: @ardaozkal Unknown. Let's wait until Episode 5 to see and it should give us answers.

Comment: Isn't Ep5 out already? edit: nope

Comment: @ardaozkal Ok I think it was one of those scenes that will NEVER be in the game. It's not part of Episode 5.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a thing in the end of the game you would be greeted with a fun cutscene about a young Axel and a young Jesse playing with snow balls in the first episode its already clear that Axel was his second friend (Reuben was the first) seeing from his clothes he seems to be a timid farm boy but it was taken down

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).